# html navigational menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using html nav bar in wordpress

my html nav bar code

```
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/" class="active">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=172">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-star"></i>
                            About </a>
                                               </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=176">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-th-large"></i>
                            Gallery</a>
                                               </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=174">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-comments"></i>
                            Services</a>
                                               </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=4">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-shopping-cart"></i>
                            Shop</a>
                                               </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=187">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-pencil"></i>
                            Blog</a></li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=145">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-plus-sign"></i>
                            Events</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/?page_id=178">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-map-marker"></i>
                            Contact</a>

                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </nav>
```

I have tried to create a conditional tags for each page like below 
 example for home

```
                  <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
           <li class="active">
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/" class="active">
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.siteurl.com/shop/" >
                            <i class="icon-nav icon-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

But this is not working
how to active the menu icons when we view the respective pages 
If i use direct html navigational menu

Comment: Why don't you use the built in wordpress menu system? It will add active state for you

Comment: i want to diplay icons above the menu item and i dont know how to create a menu system for wordpress can u suggest how to start

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this is by using the wordpress navigation system

`http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu`

A lot of work has gone into their system, so there's no reason why you would want to replicate it.

Comment: how can i get the icons on the menu items?

Comment: If you activate the wp-nav and then inspect the menu items (`li`s) you will see that they will have an `active` class or not, depends if you are on the page corresponding to that menu item. You would then need to modify that class accordingly in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from reading the Codex (essential), you can search for [tutorials, articles and Q&A's](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp_nav_menu%20icons), there are plenty of them.

#### [WordPress Wp_Nav_Menu with Icons and Active Item Highlight](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-tutorial/)

> We will be doing:
>
> - Home link in our wp_nav_menu that always gets current blog url
> - Customize each menu item as you want
> - Put pretty icons in our menu
> - Active item highlight

#### [Function Examination: wp_nav_menu](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/function-examination-wp_nav_menu/)

> In this tutorial, we’ll dive deep into everything that the
>   `wp_nav_menu` function can do, use the [Walker Class](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/) to add a sub
>   description, and touch on some of its related functions.